# Sending \0 character over UDP c++

Tags: c++, udp, send

I'm trying to send the following array of characters over an udp socket 0x11 0x00 0x00 0x00 0xb6 0x00 0x00 0x00 0xc7. I cant get it fixed. The char array always terminates at the first 0x00 character.

tried string and array of char, tried '\0' '\0' and '\', '0' but nothing seems to work.

```
    string request_soladin_meter_data_command="\x11";

//  sendudppacket (Soladin_ipaddress,5007+count,request_soladin_meter_data_command);

    struct sockaddr_in udpaddr;
    int udpsocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (udpsocket == -1) 
        {
            printf("Could not create socket");
        }

     udpaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
     udpaddr.sin_port =htons(5007+count);
     udpaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(Soladin_ipaddress);
     
     //checks connection 
     if (connect(udpsocket,(struct sockaddr *)&udpaddr, sizeof(udpaddr)) < 0) 
     {
       perror("Connection error");
     }
//   sends message

    send(udpsocket,request_soladin_meter_data_command.c_str(),request_soladin_meter_data_command.length(),0);

type here
```

Comment: possibly use data(), not c_str()

Comment: Works for me.  Maybe if you included your code that tries to send `'\0'` that would be helpful.

Comment: I have this code that doesn't work, but instead I'm going to post some code that does work. Amazing, how do you expect anyone to tell what mistake you made?

Comment: This should work `string request_soladin_meter_data_command{'\x11', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\xb6','\0', '\0', '\0', '\xc7'};` Assuming there isn't some other error somewhere in the code you haven't shown us.

Answer (score 0):

```
string request_soladin_meter_data_command="\x11";
```

Literal character strings, always get terminated by a `\x00` byte. That's what they are, by definition.

`std::string`'s constructor that takes a literal `const char *` as its parameter looks for this `00` byte, in order to figure out how long the string is. That's the only way to figure it out. There is no other way.

All your attempts to stuff a `\x00` into the literal string are doomed to a failure. The suffering `std::string` constructor in question has no idea that this is a fake trailing `00` byte, and not the real one. So it always takes everything up to the first `\x00` it sees, and that's your `std::string`. Enjoy it.

There are other `std::string` constructors that do not take a `const char *` for a parameter which can be used to construct an actual `std::string` with a `\x00` byte. Such as a constructor that takes iterators to the beginning and the one-past-the end sequence that defines the new string. Or, you can just construct an empty string and stuff a 0 byte into it:

```
string request_soladin_meter_data_command;

request_soladin_meter_data_command.push_back(0);
```

And now:

```
send(udpsocket,request_soladin_meter_data_command.c_str(),request_soladin_meter_data_command.length(),0);
```

this will happily see a `std::string` with one byte, `length()` will be 1, and there goes your happy little `\x00` byte, over the socket.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the string literal: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal

If you construct a std::string out of a `const char*` it will interpret it as a c string, ad use `strlen` logic to find the length.

Constructing out of initializer list is also possible.
see:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string

Comment: Thx all for the clear explanation of what is happening.I now did the following for the variable : const char request_soladin_meter_data_command[]={0x11,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xb6,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xc7}; and changed the send line into this :  send(udpsocket,request_soladin_meter_data_command,sizeof(request_soladin_meter_data_command),0); and now it works perefectly